# VHDL: Unable to read output status

Tags: compiler-errors, vhdl, modelsim

I'm attempting to compile in ModelSim 10.0 and I receive a compile error stating:
'Cannot read output status'.

Here's a snippet of the code.  It'd be brilliant if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
entity controller_entity is
generic( entryCount : positive := 2;
         ....);
port(
    clk         : in  std_logic;
    ....
    entry_car_entered : out std_logic_vector(0 to entryCount-1)
);
end entity controller_entity;

architecture controller_v1 of controller_entity is
signal cars_entered : std_logic_vector(0 to entryCount-1);

component entry is
    port(
        clk       : in  std_logic;
        ....
        car_passed: out std_logic  --Output to higher level
    );
end component;

begin   
    CREATE_ENTRANCES: for i in 0 to entryCount-1 generate
                entryi : entry port map(clk => clk,
                        ....
                car_passed => entry_car_entered(i) -- This line causes the problem.                                             

                        end generate CREATE_ENTRANCES;

    .....

);
end architecture controller_v1;
```

I think I can fix this if I switch to compiling with VHDL 2008 but I'm trying to stick with 1993.  Any advice on this issue would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Your code snippet contains no output named status and doesn't reproduce the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VHDL-2008 allows read of a port in `out` mode, but previous VHDL versions do not, so based on the error message 'Cannot read output status', and your comment about fixing the problem through use of VHDL-2008, it sounds like this is the problem.

However, the error message may actually be 'Cannot read output "status"', where "status" is a reference to an output named "status" elsewhere in undisclosed code.  You may want to search for "status" in all code, to see if a "status" port with mode `out` is referenced for read.

If so, the problem can be fixed in VHDL-2002 if an internal signal is driven by the component, and the internal signal then drives the `out` port.  This internal signal may then be read internally.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering.  I missed the quotations marks on either side of the status, clearly wrongly dismissing them as irrelevant.  I'll try what you suggest and create internal signals. Do you know if this actually impacts on the synthesis opposed to me directly reading the output port?

Comment: Synthesis result is the same with direct connection as with intermediate signal; in both case it will just be a data connection.  Simulation will have an additional delta delay when the intermediate signal is used, but this will not have any effect if test benches and written in a robust way.

Comment: I've fixed the issue and it now compiles with the older version; thanks very much for your help!