# VHDL Counter circuit error

Tags: vhdl, counter, bit, modelsim

As part of a group project I am to build a counter circuit for a circuit which is to deliver a payload of each of the group members first names in ASCII code.  I am tasked with building a counter circuit for the receiving side of the circuit.  I am using D type flip flops to do this.  The overall circuit I am building is 19 8 bit branches with one carry.  Here is my code for the D type flip flop, the 8 bit branch and then the overall circuit.

#### D type flip flop

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity DFF1 is port (
    d1,clk1,reset1,set1 : in STD_LOGIC;
    q1 : out STD_LOGIC);
end DFF1;

architecture DFF1 of DFF1 is
begin
    process(clk1,reset1,set1)
    begin
        if reset1='1' then
            q1 <= '0';
        elsif set1='1' then
            q1 <= '1';
        elsif clk1'event and clk1='1' then
            q1 <= d1;
        end if;
    end process;
end DFF1;
```

#### 8 Bit counter

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

Entity counter is port (
    d, clk, set,  : in std_logic;
    reset, q : out std_logic);
end entity counter;

architecture ARCH1 of counter is
    component DFF1
        port(d1, clk1, reset1, set1 : in std_logic;
             q1 : out std_logic);
    end component;

    signal qd1, qd2, qd3, qd4, qd5, qd6, qd7, sr1, sr2, sr3, sr4, sr5, sr6, sr7 : std_logic;

begin

    DFF11: DFF1 port map (d1=>d,   clk1=>clk, set1=>set, q1=>qd1, reset1=>sr1);
    DFF12: DFF1 port map (d1=>qd1, clk1=>clk, set1=>sr1, q1=>qd2, reset1=>sr2);
    DFF13: DFF1 port map (d1=>qd2, clk1=>clk, set1=>sr2, q1=>qd3, reset1=>sr3);
    DFF14: DFF1 port map (d1=>qd3, clk1=>clk, set1=>sr3, q1=>qd4, reset1=>sr4);
    DFF15: DFF1 port map (d1=>qd4, clk1=>clk, set1=>sr4, q1=>qd5, reset1=>sr5);
    DFF16: DFF1 port map (d1=>qd5, clk1=>clk, set1=>sr5, q1=>qd6, reset1=>sr6);
    DFF17: DFF1 port map (d1=>qd6, clk1=>clk, set1=>sr6, q1=>qd7, reset1=>sr7);
    DFF18: DFF1 port map (d1=>qd7, clk1=>clk, set1=>sr7, q1=>q,   reset1=>reset);

end ARCH1;
```

#### Complete counter

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

Entity complete_counter is port (
    clk0, set0, d0  : in std_logic;
    q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, q10, q11, q12, q13, q14, q15, q16, q17, q18, q19, q20, reset  : out std_logic);
end entity complete_counter;

architecture ARCH2 of complete_counter is
    component counter
        port (d, clk, set  : in std_logic;
        reset, q : out std_logic);
    end component;

    signal sr1, sr2, sr3, sr4, sr5, sr6, sr7, sr8, sr9, sr10, sr11, sr12, sr13, sr14, sr15, sr16, sr17, sr18, sr19 : std_logic;

begin

    cc1:  counter port map (clk=>clk0, set=>set0, d=>d0,  q=>q1,  reset=>sr1);
    cc2:  counter port map (clk=>clk0, set=>sr1,  d=>q1,  q=>q2,  reset=>sr2);
    cc3:  counter port map (clk=>clk0, set=>sr2,  d=>q2,  q=>q3,  reset=>sr3);
    cc4:  counter port map (clk=>clk0, set=>sr3,  d=>q3,  q=>q4,  reset=>sr4);
    cc5:  counter port map (clk=>clk0, set=>sr4,  d=>q4,  q=>q5,  reset=>sr5);
    cc6:  counter port map (clk=>clk0, set=>sr5,  d=>q5,  q=>q6,  reset=>sr6);
    cc7:  counter port map (clk=>clk0, set=>sr6,  d=>q6,  q=>q7,  reset=>sr7);
    cc8:  counter port map (clk=>clk0, set=>sr7,  d=>q7,  q=>q8,  reset=>sr8);
    cc9:  counter port map (clk=>clk0, set=>sr8,  d=>q8,  q=>q9,  reset=>sr9);
    cc10: counter port map (clk=>clk0, set=>sr9,  d=>q9,  q=>q10, reset=>sr10);
    cc11: counter port map (clk=>clk0, set=>sr10, d=>q10, q=>q11, reset=>sr11);
    cc12: counter port map (clk=>clk0, set=>sr11, d=>q11, q=>q12, reset=>sr12);
    cc13: counter port map (clk=>clk0, set=>sr12, d=>q12, q=>q13, reset=>sr13);
    cc14: counter port map (clk=>clk0, set=>sr13, d=>q13, q=>q14, reset=>sr14);
    cc15: counter port map (clk=>clk0, set=>sr14, d=>q14, q=>q15, reset=>sr15);
    cc16: counter port map (clk=>clk0, set=>sr15, d=>q15, q=>q16, reset=>sr16);
    cc17: counter port map (clk=>clk0, set=>sr16, d=>q16, q=>q17, reset=>sr17);
    cc18: counter port map (clk=>clk0, set=>sr17, d=>q17, q=>q18, reset=>sr18);
    cc19: counter port map (clk=>clk0, set=>sr18, d=>q18, q=>q19, reset=>sr19);
    cc20: counter port map (clk=>clk0, set=>sr19, d=>q19, q=>q20, reset=>sr20);

end ARCH2;
```

When I compile the complete counter, I get 21 errors, all sounding similar:

```
Error: C:/Users/Connor Doherty/Documents/Modelsim/Complete Counter.vhd(21): Cannot read output "q1".<br/>
   VHDL 2008 allows reading outputs.<br/>
   This facility is enabled by compiling with -2008.<br/>
Error: C:/Users/Connor Doherty/Documents/Modelsim/Complete Counter.vhd(22): Cannot read output "q2".<br/>
   VHDL 2008 allows reading outputs.<br/>
   This facility is enabled by compiling with -2008.<br/>
Error: C:/Users/Connor Doherty/Documents/Modelsim/Complete Counter.vhd(23): Cannot read output "q3".<br/>
   VHDL 2008 allows reading outputs.<br/>
   This facility is enabled by compiling with -2008.<br/>
Error: C:/Users/Connor Doherty/Documents/Modelsim/Complete Counter.vhd(24): Cannot read output "q4".<br/>
   VHDL 2008 allows reading outputs.<br/>
   This facility is enabled by compiling with -2008.<br/>
Error: C:/Users/Connor Doherty/Documents/Modelsim/Complete Counter.vhd(25): Cannot read output "q5".<br/>
   VHDL 2008 allows reading outputs.<br/>
   This facility is enabled by compiling with -2008.<br/>
```

This continues to 21 errors. I'm unsure as to how to fix this error, can anyone help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VHDL: Unable to read output status](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22120218/vhdl-unable-to-read-output-status)

Answer (score 3):

As the error message says, you cannot read the signal value of an output port within the entity. You will have to use an additional internal signal, e.g. have a  `signal q1_i : std_logic;`, replace all `q1` with `q1_i` and finally connect the internal signal with the output port `q1 <= q1_i;`

Comment: Ok I've modified it to:

cc1: counter port map (clk=>clk0, set=>set0, d=>d0, q=>q1, q1_1=>q1, reset=>sr1);
cc2: counter port map (clk=>clk0, set=>sr1, d=>q1_1, q2=>q1_2, q=>q2, reset=>sr2);

However its now saying 'unknown formal identifier' for q1_i.  How do I fix this?  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Are you mistaking `q1_i` and `q1_1`? The suffix is a letter, not a number.