# I cant compile this VHDL code because of z but i dont know why and how to fix it

Tags: compilation, vhdl, vlsi

Im getting this error in compiling this VHDL code with ModelSim:

```
** Error: testVHDL_5.vhd(14): Cannot read output "z".
#   VHDL 2008 allows reading outputs.
#   This facility is enabled by compiling with -2008.
```

VHDL code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

entity gate_1 is
    port(
        a, b, c : in std_logic;
        x, z : out std_logic
        );
end gate_1;

architecture arch1 of gate_1 is 
begin -- rt1
    z <= b or c;
    x <= a and b and z;
end arch1;
```

testVHDL_5 is the name of my file.
I know in the problem is that z cant be used in x. Can someone explain why and suggest a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VHDL: Unable to read output status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22120218/vhdl-unable-to-read-output-status)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an internal signal to assign (b or c) and use that for calculating x.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

entity gate_1 is
  port(
    a, b, c : in  std_logic;
    x, z    : out std_logic
    );
end gate_1;

architecture arch1 of gate_1 is
  signal temp : std_logic;
begin 
  temp <= b or c;
  x    <= a and b and temp;
  z    <= temp;
end arch1;
```

You don't need to enable VHDL 2008 for this.

As @oldfart said, Please do not use x,z. Use meaningful names.

Comment: IMO this is the better solution as using a port of mode `out` as an input is likely to confuse somebody in the future. I would however avoid using signal names like `temp`; perhaps something like `z_sig` or even `z_temp` would be better (as would not using `x` or `z` at all).

Comment: Agree that. Moreover, looks like OP is unaware of the usage of internal signals. I never used/will never use `temp` as signal name. Something meaningful to the context.

Answer (score 2):

> I know in the problem is that z cant be used in x.

Yes, that is what the error message says.

> Can someone explain why

Because you can't read an output in VHDL in versions before 2008.

> and suggest a solution.

Compile using the 2008 VHDL version.

And please do NOT use port names like like x and z. They are too easily confused with std_logic values of 'X' and 'Z'.

Comment: I can't tell that because I have no idea what you want the code to do. It seem a simple OR and an AND function.