# Getting "test2.vhd(43): VHDL Compiler exiting" error with if-statement on commented out lines but not with the "sum2" lines

Tags: vhdl

As the title says, I'm getting a compiler exiting error with the if-statement when I use the lines commented out with the "sum" value but not with the "sum" 2 value and I'm not sure why.

Code:

```
library ieee;      
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all; 
use ieee.numeric_std.all; 
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;            
                                                
entity test2 is port 

(                   
    a, b                                :   IN  unsigned( 3 DOWNTO 0 );
    cin                                 :   IN  unsigned;
    sum                                 :   OUT unsigned( 4 DOWNTO 0 )
);                                          

end test2;                      

architecture behavioral of test2 is

signal a_5, b_5, cin_5, sum2    : unsigned(4 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal x, y                     : unsigned(4 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal z                        : std_logic;

begin

    a_5     <= ('0' & a);
    b_5     <= ('0' & b);
    cin_5   <= ('0' & '0' & '0' & '0' & cin);

    sum     <= a_5 + b_5 + cin_5;
    sum2    <= a_5 + b_5 + cin_5;

    process (sum2, b_5)
    --process (sum, b_5)
    begin
        if (sum2 > b_5) then
        --if (sum > b_5) then
            z <= '1';       
        else
            z <= '0';
        end if;
    end process;

end behavioral;
```

For some context:

I'm working on an adder that adds two 4bit numbers and eventually displays the decimal value on a 7seg display.

I want to take the "sum" value and check if it is greater than decimal value 9 and if so then it sets a flag to always have the 7seg display for the 10s value display a 1. (I only need to count up to decimal value 19). I can probably do this another method but I started doing it this way and got stuck here and I think this is something fundamental I am just not understanding.

Comment: In -2008 ports of mode out had there semantics changed to match that of mode buffer allowing them to be evaluated. Previously ports of mode out could not  be read. Provide your complete error message. You could use -2008 mode, use an internal signal or variable to hold an intermediary value assigned to the port of mode out, or  use mode buffer (supported in IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 RTL Synthesis, now withdrawn).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VHDL: Unable to read output status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22120218/vhdl-unable-to-read-output-status)

Answer (score 0):

sum is a port, which has the type "out". Ports out type "out" can't be read. If you want to read an output port, you must use the type "buffer". sum2 instead is a signal, which can always be read
(By the way you should only use numeric_std and not std_logic_unsigned, which is an old solution and not preferred anymore).

Comment: Vhdl 2008 added the ability to read ports of mode out.